# Slice a string at character

Tags: javascript, html

Im pretty new to js so I hope this isnt a dumb question.

Im trying to slice the username string after a certain character ("."). This is what Ive tried so far.

Original Username: john.smith
The output I want: john

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Strings</h1>
<h2>The slice() Method</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "John.Smith"; 
let result = text.slice(0, ".");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There is no output with the '.' parameter.

Does anyone know if there is way to slice the string at the '.' or is there another function. I dont want to use an array in this case.

Comment: [String.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: use .split('.') instead of slice(). Using split will give you an array

Comment: I suggest [looking through the methods of strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). You can combine `indexOf` with `substring` (or `slice`) to do what you want without an array.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an array when that's the easiest/simplest thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let result = text.split(".")[0];
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.
Thanks.

Comment: But that uses an array, which they've said they don't want to do. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, thats correct. Didnt said it that precisely that I didnt want to get an array returned. This is exactly what I was looking for :D.

Comment: `let result = text.replace(/\..*$/, '');`


This might be an another approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it for you. Hope you like this.
Thanks!

The **indexOf**() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.
`Syntax`: indexOf(searchElement)
**E.g**

let text = "John.Smith";

console.log(text.indexOf('.')); // 4

```js
let text = "John.Smith";
// let result = text.split('.')[0];
let result = text.slice(0, text.indexOf('.'));

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```